# WP-CRM plugin is not saving data ? am I missing some setting?

Tags: wordpress, crm

Unfortunately wp-crm forum has no activity https://usabilitydynamics.com/forums/ so I am asking this question at SO.

I am using wp-crm https://usabilitydynamics.com/products/wp-crm/ which allows to create form and it saves data at the backend. I have done everything right but after filling the form, it doesn't redirect anywhere and the data doesn't get saved.

Is there anyone who has any idea why this is happening and what I can do to fix it ? I know it is a long shot but hoping to get some help from SO :)

EDIT - I got it working by changing the theme

Answer (score 0):

How many attributes do you try to save in this tab? Try to increase max_input_vars on your server.

Regards, UD Team.

Comment: Hi Sorry, this was the theme problem, I have got it fixed now by changing the theme, Thanks